# UIPickerView with many different lists

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I am writing an application that uses a UIPickerView and populates its list items depending on previous selections by the user.  I was reading this [article](http://www.leesilver.net/1/post/2011/07/uipickerview-how-to-populate.html) and stumbled across his mention of "tags" and could not figure out how this was used.  Can someone please give me a recommendation on the best way to accomplish this, and if this "tag" feature is it, just explain how it is used?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tag is just a number that you associate with an object so that you can tell that object apart from others. So let's say you have multiple picker views. For the first picker view you can set a tag of `1`. For the second, set a tag of `2`, and so on.

In the app you're creating, since you have multiple picker views, you use tags to tell each picker view apart - `if (pickerView.tag == 1) { //first picker view code here }` - set the correct number of cells for the picker view, and populate its cells with the correct list.

Comment: so what you are saying is I can drag and drop multiple unique UIPickerViews on my view controller and just call whichever one I want and distinguish between them based on the tag I assign?

Comment: Can the same result be achieved by just having multiple NSArrays and one UIPicker and just pick which array you want to use based on previous user input for the count and content of the picker?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Since you would only have one UIPickerView in that example, you would have no need for a tag. Just set the correct array.

Comment: i am having a hard time believing that tag feature is useful, maybe it just doesnt suit my need for this instance.  Is there a situation you can think of where it is very useful to have many pickers and differentiate between them with tags?  thanks for the help

Comment: Not in this case, but tags are not specific to `UIPickerViews`. If you have more than one object of the same type and you are trying to differentiate between the different objects in the delegate methods, then the tags do become useful. Take the following: `- (void)textChanged:(UITextField *)textField { }`. If you have multiple `UITextFields` on the view, then you would need to use tags to determine which text field had its text modified. `if (textField.tag == 1) { //textField 1 changed, move text to location one } else if (textField.tag == 2) { //2 changed, move text to location two }`